# Flutter SQLite Datatype mismatch on INSERT with the correct datatypes

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter, sqlite

No matter how I've tried this I keep getting this error

```
E/SQLiteLog( 9445): (20) statement aborts at 5: [INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about) VALUES ('0.0.0.0.0.0','/data/user/0/com.shades.flidar/cache/scaled_image_picker5826102720138113893.jpg','test','35',
E/SQLiteQuery( 9445): exception: datatype mismatch (code 20 SQLITE_MISMATCH); query: INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about) VALUES ('0.0.0.0.0.0','/data/user/0/com.test.test/cache/scaled_image_picker5826102720138113893.jpg','test','35','test','test','test');
E/flutter ( 9445): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(datatype mismatch (code 20 SQLITE_MISMATCH)) sql 'INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about) VALUES ('0.0.0.0.0.0','/data/user/0/com.test.test/cache/scaled_image_picker5826102720138113893.jpg','test','35','test','test','test');' args []
```

This is the code:

```
customQuery("CREATE TABLE Profile ("
"mac TEXT,"
"image TEXT,"
"name TEXT,"
"age TEXT,"
"nationality TEXT,"
"profession TEXT,"
"about TEXT"
")");

onPressed: () {
    profile.add(Profile(
        mac: _platformVersion,
        image: imagePath,
        name: nameController.text,
        age: ageController.text,
        nationality: nationalityController.text,
        profession: professionController.text,
        about: aboutController.text));

    DBProvider.db.customQuery("INSERT Into Profile (mac,image,name,age,nationality,profession,about)"
        " VALUES ('${profile[0].mac}','${profile[0].image}',"
        "'${profile[0].name}','${profile[0].age}','${profile[0].nationality}',"
        "'${profile[0].profession}','${profile[0].about}');");
       },
```

I really can't seem to figure out why, please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`profile[0].age` should return a String data type.

Comment: Thank  you, it does return a string value